# Edit URL with description through SharePoint User Profile Web Service

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

Is it possible to add/edit a URL with a description through the user profile web service? So far I'm only able to update the actual URL, and not the description. This is the code I'm using so far:

```
PropertyData propertyData = new PropertyData
                                        {
                                            Name = propertyName,
                                            IsValueChanged = true,
                                            Values = new ValueData[1]
                                        };
propertyData.Values[0] = new ValueData { Value = value };

userProfileService.ModifyUserPropertyByAccountName(username, new[] { propertyData });
```

It would be nice to provide a description for the URL, since it's displayed on user profile pages.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your code sample that you are using something like value="http://www.microsoft.com". Have you tried value="http://www.microsoft.com,Microsoft"? Generally URLs are stored as "URL,Description".

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work, it just shows the link as "http://microsoft.com,Microsoft" in the user profile view.

Comment: Which property are you working with? I'll try to repro your issue.